# Needed assistance with moving div on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So thats my layout of my basic html page and I want my content div to move relative to the browser window size when I resize it, I have looked up many answers on this site, but none of them seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="content">
                  xyz
            </div>
        </div>
    <footer>            
    </footer>
</body>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
#container {
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width:100%; /* Sizing - any length */
margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-o-box-sizing:border-box;
-ms-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

footer {
width: 100%;
background: black;
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
}
header {
width: 100%;
background: black;
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */ why ?  margin:0 auto enough

Comment: Move how? With or without JavaScript? Which solutions did you try? How did they not work?

Comment: Something with `width:100%` hardly needs to be centered, does it?

Comment: I apologize for the vague question. I should have made it clear. So the headers and the footers resize properly when I resize my browser window but its the content which is not resizing. I tried the javascript solution where I basically get the windows screen and height on a resize using jquery but it did not work. I was looking for some CSS suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @user1386101: To center the content, you need to apply the `margin: 0 auto` onto the `#content`, not on the `#container`.

Comment: Ohh ok, makes sense now, I am sorry but I am new to CSS, thanks for your help, let me try that now

Comment: Hey Bergi, this worked and also Rich Peck's answer also helped, thank you and also I apologize for the vague question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is quite obscure, I think you're asking about retaining the div's width when you move the width of the browser. If this is the case, what I'd recommend is to use `width: 100%;` in your CSS

This will ensure you are able to keep the container's width the same size in relation to the size of the container (in this case, the window); as opposed to not being able to

It seems you've got that already?

---

If you're looking for responsive web design, you'll have to use the [`@media`](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) CSS3 feature:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .footer {
       background-color: #fff;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to always have it centered, you have to specify a width of less than 100% (either in px or %), otherwise the container will always use the full width of your viewport and therefore have no reason to 'move'.